# Graph Algorithm: Similar to TSP

Tags: algorithm

I want to solve a problem similar to the TSP( Travelling Salesman Problem).

I have N ( N > 0, N < 20 ) nodes and I must visit all nodes.

The cost between nodes are equal.

I can visit a node unlimited times.

I want to find more than one path and the cost has no restriction.

Tell me some effective algorithms about this problem?

Comment: Does this relate to the commercial software product *Mathematica* by Wolfram Research?  If not we should move it to a different Stack Exchange chapter.

Comment: Just do a random walk :P

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question. Is the graph a complete graph?

Comment: Yes, Complete Graph Problem. But it has a condition, that can visit count of each node is not restricted.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide few input datasets

Comment: That should be easy, e.g. you can just use every possible spanning tree of the graph, for example a depth-first tree starting from a node

Answer (score 0):

Why not a a simple DFS run? `O(V + E)`

Multiple paths can be obtained by starting the algorithm from different roots.

```
bool[] visited;
List<int> path;
void Visit(int u)
{
    if (visited[u]) return; // only visit each node once
    visited[u] = true;
    path.Add(u); // add initially to path
    int pathSize = path.Count;
    foreach(int v in nbs[u]) {
        Visit(v);
        if(path.Count > pathSize)
        {
            // if another node was visited, add this node again
            // so we can move to the next unvisited subtree
            path.Add(u);
            pathSize = path.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

- Starting from 1: *1 > 2 > 1 > 3 > 4 > 3 > 1*
- Starting from 2: *2 > 1 > 3 > 4 > 3 > 1 > 2*

[image: Labeled graph]

You can also update the algorithm that it ends the moment the last node is visited.